# Docker container doesnot reflect changes on machines other than it was created

Tags: docker, virtualenv, dockerfile

So I have a Dockerfile, using which I create an image. The instruction in Dockerfile are:

```
#This is a docker file

FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER amit 

# Install python-pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip

# Install virtual-env
RUN mkdir ~/.virtualenvs

RUN pip install virtualenv

RUN pip install virtualenvwrapper

RUN touch ~/.bashrc

RUN echo "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN /bin/bash -c "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh &&  mkvirtualenv be"

# INSTALL REQUIRED PACKAGES
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    xclip \
    python-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libpam0g-dev \
    sqlite3 \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    subversion \
    g++ \
    libxslt1-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    swig \
    node \
    git \
    libssl-dev

# Expose port
EXPOSE 5000


# Get the source  ideally one should do a get on source release
COPY src /src

WORKDIR /src

RUN touch installer.sh

RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" >> installer.sh

RUN echo "source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`" >> installer.sh

RUN echo "workon be" >> installer.sh

RUN echo "./tools/install_dependencies" >> installer.sh

RUN echo "deactivate be" >> installer.sh

RUN chmod +x installer.sh
```

Now I build an image from this. I execute the installer.sh by running the docker container and everything works great.

But when some one pulls this very image from the repository , and runs the file installer.sh, there is an error stating that virtualenv be is not present and then one has to do "mkvirtualenv be" once again.
What is wrong here? Shouldn't the "virtualenv be" automatically be present in the container?

Comment: maybe the image on the repository is not up to date?

Comment: Do the working and non-working containers have the same image id? (i.e. the pulled image is the same as the image you are working with)

Comment: Also how are you running the containers? Are you mounting any volumes?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The image in the repository is up to date. No I am not mounting any volume, just using run docker -it to run the container and the pulled image has the same image id as the working one.

Comment: Are you sure this image was pulled? Try delete the old version and repull.

Comment: Yup , I am pretty sure about the version of the image pulled , since there this is the very first image of the repository.

Comment: Ok  found something new. The containers that run on my machine(machine on which the image was created ) has a user defined bashrc with the contents being the results of these 2 lines of the Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                    RUN echo "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: But the containers that run on other machines where the image was pulled from the repository , doesnot have a user defined bashrc file.